# excel dynamically generate weekdays unitl today (included)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My objective is to have 1 formula (better) or macro that can automatically generate all weekdays from a given day cell reference until today (included).

Say I have a A1 cell with "2022-01-01", how can I generate a column with values that will include all weekdays until today? (this will be a dynamic length as everyday is updated)

Like:

[image]

Edit: using Office 2019 so SEQUENCE() function not working

Answer (score 3):

put this in your first cell:

```
=WORKDAY(A1-1,SEQUENCE(NETWORKDAYS(A1,TODAY())))
```

This requires the dynamic array formula Sequence.  It will spill the results down.

[image]

With out SEQUENCE, put this in the first cell and copy down till you get blanks and beyond if you want each new day to continue to appear:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(A1-1,ROW($ZZ1))>TODAY(),"",WORKDAY(A1-1,ROW($ZZ1)))
```

Comment: hey Scott, thanks for the reply - sorry to mention but I am using office 2019 so there is not SEQUENCE() there...

Comment: @TomLau see edit.  No need for volatile INDIRECT.

Comment: thanks Scott, it works now. Seems there is no way for automatically generating the new date (today) in office 2019... need to copy the formula everyday.

Comment: @TomLau Just fill the column with the formula.  Then each new day it will change the result from `""` to the new date.  Until there is a date to put in it the reult will look blank.